# Why references are not adding from bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, two-column

Initially, I have added my bib file in the single column and its work correctly, While when I use into two columns format it gives below error.

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6800 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: Paper.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Paper.aux (There was 1 error message)

Process exited with error(s)
```

What should I do to solve this problem?
This is the code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{el-author}

%\usepackage[...]{...}      This has been commented out as we are not using any additional packages here.  On the whole, they should be unnecessary.
\newcommand{\hH}{\hat{H}}
\newcommand{\D}{^\dagger}
\newcommand{\ua}{\uparrow}
\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\nc{\da}{\downarrow} \nc{\hc}{\hat{c}} \nc{\hS}{\hat{S}}
\nc{\bra}{\langle} \nc{\ket}{\rangle} \nc{\eq}{equation (\ref}
\nc{\h}{\hat} \nc{\hT}{\h{T}}\nc{\be}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\nc{\ee}{\end{eqnarray}}\nc{\rd}{\textrm{d}}\nc{\e}{eqnarray}\nc{\hR}{\hat{R}}\nc{\Tr}{\mathrm{Tr}}
\nc{\tS}{\tilde{S}}\nc{\tr}{\mathrm{tr}}\nc{\8}{\infty}\nc{\lgs}{\bra\ua,\phi|}\nc{\rgs}{|\ua,\phi\ket}
\nc{\hU}{\hat{U}}\nc{\lfs}{\bra\phi|}\nc{\rfs}{|\phi\ket}\nc{\hZ}{\hat{Z}}\nc{\hd}{\hat{d}}\nc{\mD}{\mathcal{D}}
\nc{\bd}{\bar{d}}\nc{\bc}{\bar{c}}\nc{\mc}{\mathcal}\nc{\ea}{eqnarray}\nc{\mG}{\mathcal{G}}\nc{\bce}{\begin{center}}
\nc{\ece}{\end{center}}
\date{12th December 2011}

\begin{document}

\title{Instructions and example template for \LaTeX{} submissions to \emph{Electronics Letters}}

\author{J. Smith and A. N. Other}

\abstract{This document describes how to use the el-author.cls file and how to format your \LaTeX submissions
correctly for \emph{Electronics Letters}. It also serves as a template, so that you can simply
copy the text from this example .tex file and replace it with your own.  We have tried to cover the basic
}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\verb"el-author.cls" is used in a similar fashion to the standard \verb"article.cls" file. However, the \verb"el-author.cls" file must be copied \cite{Preece2009, Shoaib2013a} into the same directory as the .tex file you wish to compile for submission. 



\bibliography{library}
\end{document}


%\verb"\end{document}"
```

Comment: Where in the document do you have the line with `\bibliographystyle`?

Comment: I had added the `\bibliographystyle` but it did not work

Comment: If you add `\bibliographystyle{<yourstyle>}` the error message from BIbTeX should be different. Please update your question with the new code and try again. Report the new error message as well.

Comment: @moewe I have checked right now via adding  `\bibliographystyle {<IEEEtrans>}` same error is throwing

Comment: If your system is case sensitive it should be `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}` (note that there should be no `<` or `>`, I only used them to indicate that `yourstyle` is a variable). If you do have a `\bibliographystyle` command BibTeX should not complain about a missing `\bibstyle`. Unfortunately, your code is not a minimal example and I don't know wehere to get `el-author`, so I can't test anything. Please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: After adding a `\bibliographystyle` directive, did you re-run LaTeX *before* running BibTeX and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: Yes, I had  @Mico

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you obtained the files `el-author.cls`, `sample.tex`, and `sample.pdf` from  https://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/el/author-guide.

If that's the case, do note that the sample file contains the following  hand-built `thebibliography` environment.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{1}
Anderson, P.: `A poor man's derivation of scaling laws for the 
Kondo problem', \textit{J. Phys. C.}, 1960, \textbf{3}, p. 2436

\bibitem{2}
Coleman, P.: `1/N expansion for the Kondo lattice', 
\textit{Phys. Rev. B}, 1983, \textbf{28}, pp. 5255-5262

\bibitem{3}
Ludwig, I. and Ludwig A. W. W.: `Kondo effect induced by a 
magnetic field', \textit{Phys. Rev. B}, 2001, \textbf{64}, p. 045328

\end{thebibliography}
```

Observe that all three sample entries are of the same type (journal articles); no guidance whatsoever is given on how to format books, working papers, etc. The instruction `\begin{thebibliography}{}` should really be `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`. I'd say it's also bad form to give citation keys named `1`, `2`, and `3`. Finally, it appears to be the case that a comma is missing between `Ludwig` and `A. W. W.`.

Sadly, the sample also provides no guidance on how one might create a bibliography using software such as BibTeX. The only thing that's really clear is that numeric-style citation call-outs should be employed.

I'm not aware of any readily-available bibliography styles that implement the template's largely implicit bibliography formatting requirements. I'd start with the `abbrv` bibliography style. If the journal's editorial staff sees fit to complain about this formatting choice, just ask them to provide a more suitable  bibliography style.